# Split paragraph in to lines with PHP

Tags: php

I have a long string as below:

```
Offset(V) Name PID PPID Thds Hnds Sess Wow64 Start Exit 0x819cc830 System 4 0 51 254 -1 0 0x817e4670 smss.exe 360 4 3 19 -1 0 2008-11-26 07:38:11 UTC+0000 0x8181bd78 csrss.exe 596 360 10 322 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:13 UTC+0000 0x8182b100 winlogon.exe 620 360 16 503 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:14 UTC+0000 0x8183ba78 services.exe 672 620 15 245 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:15 UTC+0000 0x817dbc30 lsass.exe 684 620 21 347 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:15 UTC+0000 0x81859d70 svchost.exe 844 672 19 198 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:18 UTC+0000 0x8183d360 svchost.exe 932 672 10 229 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:18 UTC+0000 0x818a2300 svchost.exe 1064 672 63 1308 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:20 UTC+0000 0x817f7da0 svchost.exe 1164 672 5 77 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:23 UTC+0000 0x8180e6f0 svchost.exe 1264 672 14 209 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:25 UTC+0000 0x817ca478 explorer.exe 1516 1452 12 362 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:27 UTC+0000 0x816e75e8 spoolsv.exe 1648 672 12 112 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:28 UTC+0000 0x816af860 VMwareTray.exe 1896 1516 1 26 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:31 UTC+0000 0x816af448 VMwareUser.exe 1904 1516 1 28 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:31 UTC+0000 0x816a13c0 VMwareService.e 1756 672 3 45 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:45 UTC+0000 0x816557e0 alg.exe 512 672 6 105 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:53 UTC+0000 0x81643b28 wuauclt.exe 1372 1064 8 225 0 0 2008-11-26 07:39:38 UTC+0000 0x8164e3a8 wscntfy.exe 560 1064 1 31 0 0 2008-11-26 07:44:57 UTC+0000
```

And I want to break this into lines with proper alignment same like the below screenshot using php. 
Please click this link to see the screenshot http://screenshot.net/96ql5c4

I have tried it with expolde function as below but I cannot get the result

$result = "Offset(V) Name PID PPID Thds Hnds Sess Wow64 Start Exit 0x819cc830 System 4 0 51 254 -1 0 0x817e4670 smss.exe 360 4 3 19 -1 0 2008-11-26 07:38:11 UTC+0000 0x8181bd78 csrss.exe 596 360 10 322 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:13 UTC+0000 0x8182b100 winlogon.exe 620 360 16 503 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:14 UTC+0000 0x8183ba78 services.exe 672 620 15 245 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:15 UTC+0000 0x817dbc30 lsass.exe 684 620 21 347 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:15 UTC+0000 0x81859d70 svchost.exe 844 672 19 198 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:18 UTC+0000 0x8183d360 svchost.exe 932 672 10 229 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:18 UTC+0000 0x818a2300 svchost.exe 1064 672 63 1308 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:20 UTC+0000 0x817f7da0 svchost.exe 1164 672 5 77 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:23 UTC+0000 0x8180e6f0 svchost.exe 1264 672 14 209 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:25 UTC+0000 0x817ca478 explorer.exe 1516 1452 12 362 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:27 UTC+0000 0x816e75e8 spoolsv.exe 1648 672 12 112 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:28 UTC+0000 0x816af860 VMwareTray.exe 1896 1516 1 26 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:31 UTC+0000 0x816af448 VMwareUser.exe 1904 1516 1 28 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:31 UTC+0000 0x816a13c0 VMwareService.e 1756 672 3 45 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:45 UTC+0000 0x816557e0 alg.exe 512 672 6 105 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:53 UTC+0000 0x81643b28 wuauclt.exe 1372 1064 8 225 0 0 2008-11-26 07:39:38 UTC+0000 0x8164e3a8 wscntfy.exe 560 1064 1 31 0 0 2008-11-26 07:44:57 UTC+0000";

$rows = explode(" ", $result );
and when I print_r($rows); there are some empty elements on the array so if some one can help me how to code this would really appreciate.

Comment: So what's your question? And before you say, "how do I do it?", remember that questions like that are too broad and will be closed as such. So if you've written any code thus far I highly recommend adding it to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have mentioned what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you should look for is some way to separate the data into rows:

```
$source = 'Offset(V) Name PID PPID Thds Hnds Sess Wow64 Start Exit 0x819cc830 System 4 0 51 254 -1 0 0x817e4670 smss.exe 360 4 3 19 -1 0 2008-11-26 07:38:11 UTC+0000 0x8181bd78 csrss.exe 596 360 10 322 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:13 UTC+0000 0x8182b100 winlogon.exe 620 360 16 503 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:14 UTC+0000 0x8183ba78 services.exe 672 620 15 245 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:15 UTC+0000 0x817dbc30 lsass.exe 684 620 21 347 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:15 UTC+0000 0x81859d70 svchost.exe 844 672 19 198 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:18 UTC+0000 0x8183d360 svchost.exe 932 672 10 229 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:18 UTC+0000 0x818a2300 svchost.exe 1064 672 63 1308 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:20 UTC+0000 0x817f7da0 svchost.exe 1164 672 5 77 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:23 UTC+0000 0x8180e6f0 svchost.exe 1264 672 14 209 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:25 UTC+0000 0x817ca478 explorer.exe 1516 1452 12 362 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:27 UTC+0000 0x816e75e8 spoolsv.exe 1648 672 12 112 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:28 UTC+0000 0x816af860 VMwareTray.exe 1896 1516 1 26 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:31 UTC+0000 0x816af448 VMwareUser.exe 1904 1516 1 28 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:31 UTC+0000 0x816a13c0 VMwareService.e 1756 672 3 45 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:45 UTC+0000 0x816557e0 alg.exe 512 672 6 105 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:53 UTC+0000 0x81643b28 wuauclt.exe 1372 1064 8 225 0 0 2008-11-26 07:39:38 UTC+0000 0x8164e3a8 wscntfy.exe 560 1064 1 31 0 0 2008-11-26 07:44:57 UTC+0000';
```

As there is no standard one, like a line break or a semicolon or such, you have to come up with something else. From what I can see, you should be able to break on the `Offset(V)` hexadecimal value, which seems to start each row (except for the very first). So we split on that to create an array of rows:

```
$rows = preg_split('/(?=0x[\da-f]{8})/', $source);
```

We can now loop through this array, parsing data into columns for each row:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
```

Columns can be made out of the row data by splitting on space, but there is one exception; the `Start` date may itself contain spaces and would thus create three separate columns, which is not what we want. We therefore split up each row into two parts, one with the date and one with the data of the other columns:

```
    $dateRexEx = '/(.*?) (?:(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \S+) ?)?$/';

    if (preg_match($dateRexEx, $row, $matches)) {
```

We create the `$cols` array by exploding the first set of data:

```
        $cols = explode(' ', $matches[1]);
```

Then we add any `Start` date (or just an empty column for that):

```
        @$cols[] = $matches[2];
```

From what I can see there is no value set for the `Exit` column anywhere in the string, so we just set it to an empty value. The only way it could be set at this point is if the row we're processing is the title row. (This behaviour can of course be changed if it was just missing in the small source you supplied above)

```
        @$cols[9] = $cols[9] ?: '';
```

Now we can display the formatted output using [vprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.vprintf.php)

```
        vprintf('%-10s %-15s %4s %4s %4s %4s %4s %5s %-28s %-5s' . PHP_EOL, $cols);
```

Full source code:

```
// Start HTML page
echo "<html><body><pre>", PHP_EOL;

// Define source
$source = 'Offset(V) Name PID PPID Thds Hnds Sess Wow64 Start Exit 0x819cc830 System 4 0 51 254 -1 0 0x817e4670 smss.exe 360 4 3 19 -1 0 2008-11-26 07:38:11 UTC+0000 0x8181bd78 csrss.exe 596 360 10 322 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:13 UTC+0000 0x8182b100 winlogon.exe 620 360 16 503 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:14 UTC+0000 0x8183ba78 services.exe 672 620 15 245 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:15 UTC+0000 0x817dbc30 lsass.exe 684 620 21 347 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:15 UTC+0000 0x81859d70 svchost.exe 844 672 19 198 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:18 UTC+0000 0x8183d360 svchost.exe 932 672 10 229 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:18 UTC+0000 0x818a2300 svchost.exe 1064 672 63 1308 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:20 UTC+0000 0x817f7da0 svchost.exe 1164 672 5 77 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:23 UTC+0000 0x8180e6f0 svchost.exe 1264 672 14 209 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:25 UTC+0000 0x817ca478 explorer.exe 1516 1452 12 362 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:27 UTC+0000 0x816e75e8 spoolsv.exe 1648 672 12 112 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:28 UTC+0000 0x816af860 VMwareTray.exe 1896 1516 1 26 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:31 UTC+0000 0x816af448 VMwareUser.exe 1904 1516 1 28 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:31 UTC+0000 0x816a13c0 VMwareService.e 1756 672 3 45 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:45 UTC+0000 0x816557e0 alg.exe 512 672 6 105 0 0 2008-11-26 07:38:53 UTC+0000 0x81643b28 wuauclt.exe 1372 1064 8 225 0 0 2008-11-26 07:39:38 UTC+0000 0x8164e3a8 wscntfy.exe 560 1064 1 31 0 0 2008-11-26 07:44:57 UTC+0000';

// Split rows on Offset value
$rows = preg_split('/(?=0x[\da-f]{8})/', $source);

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    // Split row data on "Start date"
    $dateRexEx = '/(.*?) (?:(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \S+) ?)?$/';

    if (preg_match($dateRexEx, $row, $matches)) {
        // Make columns by splitting on space, except for "Start" date column,
        // which needs special treatment as it contains spaces in itself
        $cols = explode(' ', $matches[1]);

        // Add any "Start" date or set an empty column
        @$cols[] = $matches[2];

        // Add an empty "Exit" value unless set (i.e. it is the title)
        @$cols[9] = $cols[9] ?: '';

        // Format output
        vprintf('%-10s %-15s %4s %4s %4s %4s %4s %5s %-28s %-5s' . PHP_EOL, $cols);
    }
}

// End HTML page
echo "</pre></body></html>", PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
Offset(V)  Name             PID PPID Thds Hnds Sess Wow64 Start                        Exit 
0x819cc830 System             4    0   51  254   -1     0                                   
0x817e4670 smss.exe         360    4    3   19   -1     0 2008-11-26 07:38:11 UTC+0000      
0x8181bd78 csrss.exe        596  360   10  322    0     0 2008-11-26 07:38:13 UTC+0000      
0x8182b100 winlogon.exe     620  360   16  503    0     0 2008-11-26 07:38:14 UTC+0000      
0x8183ba78 services.exe     672  620   15  245    0     0 2008-11-26 07:38:15 UTC+0000      
0x817dbc30 lsass.exe        684  620   21  347    0     0 2008-11-26 07:38:15 UTC+0000      
0x81859d70 svchost.exe      844  672   19  198    0     0 2008-11-26 07:38:18 UTC+0000      
0x8183d360 svchost.exe      932  672   10  229    0     0 2008-11-26 07:38:18 UTC+0000      
0x818a2300 svchost.exe     1064  672   63 1308    0     0 2008-11-26 07:38:20 UTC+0000      
0x817f7da0 svchost.exe     1164  672    5   77    0     0 2008-11-26 07:38:23 UTC+0000      
0x8180e6f0 svchost.exe     1264  672   14  209    0     0 2008-11-26 07:38:25 UTC+0000      
0x817ca478 explorer.exe    1516 1452   12  362    0     0 2008-11-26 07:38:27 UTC+0000      
0x816e75e8 spoolsv.exe     1648  672   12  112    0     0 2008-11-26 07:38:28 UTC+0000      
0x816af860 VMwareTray.exe  1896 1516    1   26    0     0 2008-11-26 07:38:31 UTC+0000      
0x816af448 VMwareUser.exe  1904 1516    1   28    0     0 2008-11-26 07:38:31 UTC+0000      
0x816a13c0 VMwareService.e 1756  672    3   45    0     0 2008-11-26 07:38:45 UTC+0000      
0x816557e0 alg.exe          512  672    6  105    0     0 2008-11-26 07:38:53 UTC+0000      
0x81643b28 wuauclt.exe     1372 1064    8  225    0     0 2008-11-26 07:39:38 UTC+0000      
0x8164e3a8 wscntfy.exe      560 1064    1   31    0     0 2008-11-26 07:44:57 UTC+0000
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Nicely explained. But I have an issue with this when I run this on localhost (xampp) I do not get the expected output but I run the same piece of code here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ I can get the expected output. I think it's because of "vprintf". My localhost php version is 5.5.9 [Apache Version  Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.9] . Please let me know how to solve this issue. Thanks

Comment: What output do you get when running locally? What is the difference to when running at the sandbox server? Do you get any errors?

Comment: This is what I get when I run it on localhost - http://screenshot.net/egez0ij but on sandbox server I get the expected output same like the output you have mentioned on your first answer.

Comment: Oh, you need to wrap the output in some HTML to be able to view it correctly in a web browser (without the textarea the sandbox is using). See updated answer for a quick fix.

Comment: I am getting the result. You saved me Thank you :)

Comment: Please mark my answer as accepted if it helped solve your problem. Good luck with your project!